# How can test if a website can work well in local IIS server?

Tags: iis

I ordered a VPS on a Microsoft Hyper-V host.  I then added my website mysite.com to the new hosting using WebsitePanel.

Before I change DNS to the new hosting, I want to test if the website will work well on the new VPS.

In IIS Manager, I right-click the folder mysite.com and choose manage website -> Browse menu item in popup menu.  IE starts with the URL http://mysite.com loaded.  It seems that IE is accessing old hosting!

How can I do view the site on my new VPS instead of the live site?

Comment: Work well?  Or just plain work at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your testing machine, override the DNS entry for mysite.com to point to the new IP address (which you need for updating DNS anyway). On Windows, edit `%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` with a text editor and add it there.

(Some antivirus block access to the hosts file by default since it is also used by malware to redirect antivirus update hosts to rogue URLs. If your AV does, just disable the feature for the test and re-enable it later.)

Answer (score 1):

think about what you said "Before I hanged DNS to new hosting, I hope to test if the website can work well in new hosting"  so if you browse to the URL it's going to point to the old site until DNS has been migrated.  To test use the new IP instead.

Comment: Thanks! I hope that the IIS in new VPS hosting can provide a temp URL to test the website, but I don't know how to do it in IIS.